# Exchange Managed API: How do I retrieve all elements that end with specific substring

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I need to find all calendar items that end with a defined substring. I know there's a SearchFilter "ContainsSubstring" but nothing like "EndsWithSubstring".

Answer (score 0):

you can try
bool string.EndsWith(string suffix)